# Unity 3, where is RegisterTypes method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I just downloaded Unity 3 to give it a try for my new project. The documentation states that this version allows Registration by Convention using the container.RegiserTypes method. But I cannot find this method anywhere. Am I missing an additional DLL? I used Nuget to add Unity 3 to my project.

Comment: Did something change in 4.0? I'm having this same problem, but taking out the ability to register by convention makes *absolutely* no sense.

Comment: In version `4.0.0.0` it is available in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you get the DLLs and are you sure you have the correct version of Unity? I added the dependency using Nuget and it worked once Microsoft.Practices.Unity was included. Version is 3.0.0. RegisterTypes is an extension method defined in [UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerregistrationbyconventionextensions_methods%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)  which may be the cause of your issue if you just added a reference to IUnityContainer and UnityContainer.

[image]

Comment: So, the solution here isn't clear. If I don't see this method (??!!?) am I missing a NuGet package, or a reference? I don't see a `using` statement in your example code, and I can't find any nuget package by that name. I have both Microsoft.Practices.Unity (version 4.0.1) and M.P.U.Configuration referenced in my project.

Comment: In the file you are trying to use the method in, do you have `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity`

Comment: yes, thanks for the response. My issue was that I'd installed Unity as a dependency on another package. That dependency specified Unity version >=2.0, so I just had version 2 installed. I'd installed Unity on its own elsewhere, and had 4.0, there, which cause the confusion.

Answer (score 15):

As of this answer the version of Unity out there is version 5.* .
If you realize your version is version 5.0 or higher, none of the above answers will apply to you because Registration By Convention is no longer distributed with Unity Core.

Unity has been broken down into a set of Packages for you to install only what you need.

If you need to do **Registration By Convention** - which is what the **RegisterTypes()** method is used for, you need to also install the **NuGet Package**, **Unity.RegistrationByConvention** (version 2.1.0 as of this writing).

Once you install it, you will have the **RegisterTypes()** method back.

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to add `using Unity.RegistrationByConvention;` instead of `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;`

Comment: Yes, Thanks for mentioning.